# Global assembly cache and dlls

Tags: c#, .net, dll

We have a class library we ve created using C# and .NET 3.5. The highest leveled namespace in the namespace hierarchy of that class library is say Abc.

When we use the output dll of the class library (Abc.MyLibrary.dll) in a test application in another test machine, it gives a compile time error saying Abc.dll is missing. 
But when we build the class library within that test machine, then it gives no error and compiles.

Is this something related to GAC or is there any other reason for this conflicting situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Error is ABC.dll is missing or Abc.MyLibrary.dll?
Does both computers have the same version of framework installed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact project settings, but Visual Studio might install the Assembly to the Global Assembly Cache.
Use Gacutil.exe *AssemblyName* from the Visual Studio Command line to check if it is installed or not.

Comment: Did you use Assembly name of AssemblyName.dll - otherwise try first without any parameters.